# How to update old value with new value in array [React native]

Tags: arrays, react-native, sorting, arraylist

I have array

```
[{
        "studentname": "abc",
        "marks": "20"
    },
    {
        "studentname": "abc2",
        "marks": "20"
    }
]
```

I have want add 10 more marks where studentname=abc into marks so how do this

eg.10+20=30
so the output will be

```
[{
        "studentname": "abc",
        "marks": "30"
    },
    {
        "studentname": "abc2",
        "marks": "20"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    const updatedArray = array.map(item => {
  if (item.studentname === "abc") {
    return {
      studentname: "abc",
      marks: parseInt(item.marks, 10) + 10
    };
  } else {
    return item;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one clean way to do it.

```js
const x= [{
        "studentname": "abc",
        "marks": "20"
    },
    {
        "studentname": "abc2",
        "marks": "20"
    }
]

x.forEach(function(obj) {
    if (obj.studentname === 'abc') {
        obj.marks = Number(obj.marks) + 10
    }
});

console.log(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const array= [{
        "studentname": "abc",
        "marks": "20"
    },
    {
        "studentname": "abc2",
        "marks": "20"
    }
]

array.map((item,index)=> {
    if (item.studentname == 'abc') {
        item.marks = Number(item.marks) + 10
    }
});

console.log("Your Updated Array Here:->",array)
```

Answer (score 0):

- Loop through the array of objects
- Check if the studentname property of the current object is equal to abc
- If it is, add 10 to the marks property of the current object
- After the loop, the array will be updated with the modified object

```js
const arr = [{"studentname": "abc", "marks": "20"},    
       {"studentname": "abc2","marks": "20" }];

for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  if (arr[i].studentname === "abc") {
        arr[i].marks = parseInt(arr[i].marks) + 10;
    }
}

console.log(arr);
```